# Select element by data attribute

Tags: jquery

Wish to update some HTML with JSON, and don't want a full blown template engine like handlebars, etc.  Thought I would just assign a data value and iterate over, but I am receiving errors.  Reference https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/, however, maybe not applicable with jQuery 3?  How can I select the elements which have a data attribute?

Side note.  While not my question, my end goal is to update the HTML with an object which contains name/values equal to the values of the data attributes I have listed below.  Please comment if there is a better way to do so.  Thanks

```
<table class='table' id="default-template">
    <tr><td>Server IP</td><td data-name="server"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Server Port</td><td data-name="port"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Reconnect Timeout (seconds)</td><td data-name="reconnectTimeout"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Response Timeout (seconds)</td><td data-name="responseTimeout"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Verbose Log</td><td data-name="verboseLog"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Device Static IP</td><td data-name="ip_address"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Router IP</td><td data-name="router_ip"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Domain Name Server IP</td><td data-name="domain_name_server_ip"></td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('#default-template').find('td:data(name)').each(function(i){
    console.log(i,this);
});
```

> display.js:20 {ip_address: "10.120.11.30/24", router_ip: "10.120.11.1", domain_name_server_ip: "10.120.11.1", server: "12.34.56.78", port: "1337", …}
>   jquery-3.2.1.js:1580 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:   unsupported pseudo: data
>       at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.2.1.js:1580)
>       at PSEUDO (jquery-3.2.1.js:1927)
>       at matcherFromTokens (jquery-3.2.1.js:2476)
>       at Sizzle.compile (jquery-3.2.1.js:2630)
>       at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.2.1.js:2716)
>       at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.js:884)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.js:2922)
>       at Object.success (display.js:21)
>       at fire (jquery-3.2.1.js:3317)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.js:3447)
>   Sizzle.error @ jquery-3.2.1.js:1580
>   PSEUDO @ jquery-3.2.1.js:1927
>   matcherFromTokens @ jquery-3.2.1.js:2476
>   Sizzle.compile @ jquery-3.2.1.js:2630
>   Sizzle.select @ jquery-3.2.1.js:2716
>   Sizzle @ jquery-3.2.1.js:884
>   find @ jquery-3.2.1.js:2922
>   success @ display.js:21
>   fire @ jquery-3.2.1.js:3317
>   fireWith @ jquery-3.2.1.js:3447
>   done @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9272
>   (anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9514
>   XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
>   send @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9566
>   ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9173
>   (anonymous) @ display.js:16
>   dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.js:5206
>   elemData.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.js:5014

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: did you include jquery-ui? this selector option is defined in jquery-ui not jquery

Comment: @ztadic91  You are absolutely correct. I hadn't noticed which obviously was the cause of the error.  Thanks

Comment: but if you need jquery-ui only for that, rather use @SWC's answer

Comment: I wouldn't include an entire other library just for this selector, especially when there's an alternative with the library you're already using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
$('#default-template td[data-name]').each(function(i){
    console.log(i,this);
});
```

That's all that's needed.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks